# How can I retreive values from firebase (one to many relationship)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, snapshot

[image: [![enter image here][]

```
"item03" : {
    "description" : "...... ",
    "image_url" : "....",
    "name" : ".....",
    "price" : "250.00"
}
```

```
item = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category")
        .child(categoryID).child("Items");
```

```
private void fetchData() {
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ItemModel> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemModel>()
            .setQuery(item, new SnapshotParser<ItemModel>() {
        
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ItemModel parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            return new ItemModel(snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(),
                    snapshot.child("description").getValue().toString(),
                    snapshot.child("image_url").getValue().toString(),
                    snapshot.child("price").getValue().toString());
        }
    }).build();

    // Set the adapter
    itemsAdapter = new ItemsRecyclerViewAdapter(options);
}
```

I can't access name, imageurl and other properties because snapshot.getvalue returns true
How can I retreive values from firebase having one to many relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read the `name`, `description` and other properties from the `"item01": true` node. That won't work, since the properties don't exist on that node.

You'll instead need to load the snapshot for that specific item, and then read the properties from *that*. This is fairly non-trivial so I highly recommend using the [`setIndexedQuery` method](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data) that was specifically made for this case.